# GoogleAppEngine Error 403

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, google-app-engine

I have coded that gae code:

index.html
    
    
     
      
      A form

```
  <!-- Simple text field -->
 <label for="name">Name </label>
 <input type="text" name="name"/>
 <br/>

  <!-- Email -->
 <label for="email">Email </label>
 <input type="email" name="email"/>
 <br/>


  <!-- Textarea -->
 <label for="description">Description </label>
 <textarea  name="description" cols="50" rows="5">Type your comment here</textarea>
 <br/>


 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Request"/>
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>FeedbackServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>at.wunderapps.servlets</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>FeedbackServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/feedback</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

servlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FeedbackServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        String description = req.getParameter("description");
        String email = req.getParameter("email");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        String msgBody = name  + description + email + " :EMAIL";

        try {
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("apps@gmail.com",
                    "Es FUNKTIONIERT!!!"));
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("my.mail@mail.com", "Your name"));
            msg.setSubject("Bestellung");
            msg.setText(msgBody);
            Transport.send(msg);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            resp.setContentType("text/plain");
            resp.getWriter().println("Something went wrong. Please try again.");
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.getWriter().println(
                "Thanks you for your feedback. An Email has been send out.");
    }
}
```

When I am doing localhost i get:

HTTP ERROR 403

Problem accessing /. Reason:

```
FORBIDDEN
```

Why?

PS.: I am running it on windows 7.

Comment: what's your opening <form> tag?

Comment: sorry i forgot to post the full code, but its there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You html page is not specifying the path to the servlet so the container is using the default /.

use

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Request" action="/feedback"/>
```